# Knockout subscribe update as text is entered into input?

Tags: knockout.js

I have an input field that is bound to an observable object.  I'm subscribing to the change so I can do some ui changes as they're entering data.  Currently the subscribe event gets called after the user clicks outside of the input.  Is there any way to change the subscribe so it updates as the user enters characters in the input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: filter, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

JS:

```
filter = ko.observable("");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the ["valueUpdate"](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) parameter / "binding" for this:

```
<input data-bind="value: someObservable, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
```